# Where to run a duplicate check for an entity

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation, design-patterns

I'm looking for advice on the "best" place to put validation logic, such as a duplicate check for an entity, when using Entity Framework Code-First, in an MVC application.

To use a simple example:

```
public class JobRole
{
  public int Id { get; set; }        
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The rule is that the "Name" field must be unique.

When I *add* a new JobRole, it is easy to run a check in the Job Role Repository that the Name doesn't already exist.

But if a user *edits* an existing JobRole, and accidentally sets the Name to one that already exists, how can I check this?

The issue is that there doesn't need to be an "update" method on the Repository, as the Job Role Entity will automatically detect changes, so there isn't a logical place to do this check before attempting to save.

I have considered two options so far:

1. Override the ValidateEntry method on the DbContext, and then when the JobRole entity is being saved with EntityState.Modified, run the duplicate check then.
2. Create some sort of duplicate-checking service, called from the Controller, before attempting a Save.

Neither really seems ideal.  Using ValidateEntry seems rather late (just before save) and hard to test.  Using a Service leaves the possibility that someone forgets to call it from a Controller, letting duplicate data through.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem with ValidateEntity appears to be that the validation occurs on SaveChanges and this is too late for you. But in Entity Framework 5.0 you can call the validation earlier if you wish using [DbContext.GetValidationErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.getvalidationerrors%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). And of course you could also just call [DbContext.ValidateEntity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.validateentity%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) directly. This is how I do it:

1. Override the `ValidateEntity` method on the `DbContext`:

   ```
   protected override DbEntityValidationResult 
                      ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry,
                      IDictionary<object, object> items)
   {
       //base validation for Data Annotations, IValidatableObject
       var result = base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, items);

       //You can choose to bail out before custom validation
       //if (result.IsValid)
       //    return result;

       CustomValidate(result);
       return result;
   }

   private void CustomValidate(DbEntityValidationResult result)
   {
       ValidateOrganisation(result);
       ValidateUserProfile(result);
   }

   private void ValidateOrganisation(DbEntityValidationResult result)
   {
       var organisation = result.Entry.Entity as Organisation;
       if (organisation == null)
           return;

       if (Organisations.Any(o => o.Name == organisation.Name 
                                  && o.ID != organisation.ID))
           result.ValidationErrors
                 .Add(new DbValidationError("Name", "Name already exists"));
   }

   private void ValidateUserProfile(DbEntityValidationResult result)
   {
       var userProfile = result.Entry.Entity as UserProfile;
       if (userProfile == null)
           return;

       if (UserProfiles.Any(a => a.UserName == userProfile.UserName 
                                 && a.ID != userProfile.ID))
           result.ValidationErrors.Add(new DbValidationError("UserName", 
                                 "Username already exists"));
   }
   ```
2. Embed `Context.SaveChanges` in a try catch and create a method to access `Context.GetValidationErrors(`). This is in my `UnitOfWork` class:

   ```
   public Dictionary<string, string> GetValidationErrors()
   {
       return _context.GetValidationErrors()
                      .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
                      .ToDictionary(x => x.PropertyName, x => x.ErrorMessage);
   }

   public int Save()
   {
       try
       {
           return _context.SaveChanges();
       }
       catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
       {
           //http://blogs.infosupport.com/improving-dbentityvalidationexception/
           var errors = e.EntityValidationErrors
             .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
             .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);

           string message = String.Join("; ", errors);

           throw new DataException(message);
       }
   }
   ```
3. In my controller, call `GetValidationErrors()` after adding the entity to the context but before `SaveChanges()`:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Create(Organisation organisation, string returnUrl = null)
   {
       _uow.OrganisationRepository.InsertOrUpdate(organisation);

       foreach (var error in _uow.GetValidationErrors())
           ModelState.AddModelError(error.Key, error.Value);

       if (!ModelState.IsValid)
           return View();

       _uow.Save();

       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
           return RedirectToAction("Index");

       return Redirect(returnUrl);
   }
   ```

My base repository class implements `InsertOrUpdate` like this:

```
    protected virtual void InsertOrUpdate(T e, int id)
    {
        if (id == default(int))
        {
            // New entity
            context.Set<T>().Add(e);
        }
        else
        {
            // Existing entity
            context.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }      
    }
```

I still recommend adding a unique constraint to the database because that will absolutely guarantee your data integrity and provide an index that can improve the efficiency, but overriding ValidateEntry gives loads of control over how and when validation occurs.

Answer (score 6):

The most reliable place to perform this logic would be the database itself by declaring an unique field constraint on the name column. When someone attempts to insert or update an existing entity and try to set its name to an existing name a constraint violation exception will be thrown that you could catch and interpret in your data access layer.

Comment: Thanks Darin.  This would be the most bullet-proof approach for unique constraints.  Although I used the example of a unique field, I have other constraints that need enforcing (eg can't save a line-item if its parent is set to read-only) and I'm trying to find the best general approach for validating entities that are in a modified state (and in particular validation that has to look outside of the entity being validated).  I'd also like to do the validation before attempting to save.

Comment: Just to extend a bit the idea, the context keeping the entities should be responsible for checking uniquness. In this case is the database, in others may be the aggregate root (for value objects) or some in a memory repository.

Comment: I agree on the constraint (and actually sent email about it today), but we may still want a validation method as well and also it's easier to make a check first.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, your first option above is *acceptable*.  The fact that another dev *might* not trap for a failure is not a huge drawback.  This is always the case with validation:  You catch it as early and elegantly as you can, but the main thing is to keep the integrity of your data.  Simpler to just have a constraint in the database and trap for that though, right?  But yes, you want to catch it as early as possible.

If you have the scope and time, better would be to have a **smarter object that would handle saving**, and perhaps other things you need handled consistently.  There's many ways of doing this.  It might be a wrapper for your entity. (See [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), though I prefer to have my object consistently have a `Data` property for access to the entity). It might require a relevant entity in order to be instantiated.  Your controller would give the entity to this smart object to save (again, perhaps instantiating this smart object with your entity.)  This smart object would know all the validation logic necessary and make sure it happens.

As an example, you could create JobRole business object.  ("busJobRole", bus prefix for "business".)  It could have a collection `DataExceptions`.  Your Controller takes the JobRole entity posted back, instantiates a busJobRole, and calls a method `SaveIfValid`, which would return *true* if the item was saved successfully and *false* if there were validation problems.  You then check the busJobRoles `DataExceptions` property for the exact problems, and fill your modelstate, etc.  Maybe like this:

```
// Check ModelState first for more basic errors, like email invalid format, etc., and react accordingly.
var jr = new busJobRole(modelJobRole);
if (jr.SaveIfValid == false) {
     ModelState.AddModelError(jr.DataExceptions.First.GetKey(0), jr.DataExceptions.First.Get(0))
}
```

We follow this model so consistently, and I made an extension method for ModelState to accept a NameValue collection (returned by business objects) (vb.net version):

```
<Extension()> _
Public Sub AddModelErrorsFromNameValueCollection(
                        ByVal theModelState As ModelStateDictionary,
                        ByVal collectionOfIssues As NameValueCollection,
                        Optional ByRef prefix As String = "")
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix) Then
        prefix = ""
    Else
        prefix = prefix & "."
    End If
    For i = 0 To CollectionOfIssues.Count - 1
        theModelState.AddModelError(prefix & CollectionOfIssues.GetKey(i), 
                        CollectionOfIssues.Get(i))
    Next
End Sub
```

this allows for quick, elegant adding of exceptions (determined by business objects) to the ModelState:

```
ModelState.AddModelErrorsFromNameValueCollection(NewApp.RuleExceptions, "TrainingRequest")
```

Your worry that other developers might not follow a plan you set up is very valid and good thinking.  **That's why your scheme needs to be consistent**.  For example, in my current project, I have two categories of classes that act as I've described.  If they're very light, and just deal with caching and validation, they are "data manager" classes (ex: *BureauDataManager*).  Some are true business domain object, very comprehensive, which I prefix with "bus" (ex: busTrainingRequest).  The former all inherit from a common base class, to ensure consistency (and reduce code of course).  **Consistency** allows for true encapsulation, for code discoverability, for the right code being in the right (single) place.

Comment: Thanks for the considered reply Patrick. I've actually implemented something vaguely similar to your approach, except that when I call SaveChanges on DbContext if there are any validation errors EF throws a DbEntityValidationException that encapsulates all the validation errors it found (including any I've added in my ValidateEntry method). So I just catch this and then convert all the errors into ModelState, which flow beautifully back to the UI.  BUT all this happens when saving and I'd like to do it earlier if possible. I'll wait for any other ideas before marking one post as the answer.

Comment: @Steve.  MVC and EF go together amazingly well, don't they?  There's so many ways to not just achieve your ends, but achieve them simply and maintainably.  OOP/D, from top to bottom.  I'm having a blast.  As my current app's requirements and capabilities grows, I'm still able to make the code-base *smaller* as many days as I make it bigger.