# Fire method on every Entity Framework Add/Update/Remove action

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Apologies if I'm missing something obvious! But I'm hoping that Entity Framework has the ability to execute a generic method on all Add/Update actions.

I'm building a custom `SaveHistory` feature that takes `T` as a param which essentially would be the Entity Framework object that's being worked on.

Core method:

```
//TODO - Requires additional logic
public void SaveHistory<T>(T type, [CallerFilePath]string callerFilePath = "")
{
    //Caller File Path just returns the location of where the method was executed
    //This enables us to retrieve the module location

    //Get the Name of the class(Type that's been passed in)
    var className = typeof(T).Name;

    //Get a collection of module names
    var enumNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof (Department));

    //Does any of the module names equal the executing assembly
    if (enumNames.Any(callerFilePath.Contains))
    {
        //Now I can search the string to see if an action came from a module
    }
    else
    {
        //If not it could be an error or calling from a core object
        //Needs work
    }
}
```

I suppose the questions is, can I centralize the method above to fire on all Add/Update/Remove actions?

If this is not possible, could anyone suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the entities being saved using the `ChangeTracker` property of `DbContext`
Override `SaveChanges` inside your implementation:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
   foreach (var e in ChangeTracker.Entries())
   {
       SaveHistory(e.Entity);
   }
   return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

If you want to validate the entity before saving then you can also access it by [overriding `ValidateEntity`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16647237/150342)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you just have to override default SaveChanges method of entity framework in dbContext class and do what you want to do. whenever you call `Context.SaveChanges()` your override method will call,

something like this

```
public override int SaveChanges() {

  // do your changes here
  return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Seems plausible...Is it possible to receive the object that's being worked on?  As SaveChanges generally "commits" not "interacts"

Comment: @TezWingfield yes you can use ChangeTracker property for that