# Web API modelstate validation: preventing duplicates on certain fields

Tags: asp.net-web-api, api-design

Say I have a model like this:

```
public class Person
{
   public int Id {get; set}
   public int Username {get; set;}
   //...other props
}
```

For a POST method, how can model state validation be used to ensure that a given username is not already used? Surely it will require a database lookup, but what is a simple, clean pattern for achieving this?

Second question: how can the same be achieved in a PUT method, where the lookup logic should ignore the one record that is being updated, since it obviously exists in the DB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to run a duplicate check for an entity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603131/where-to-run-a-duplicate-check-for-an-entity)

Comment: are you using entity framework?

Comment: Yes, I am in my data layer, but not directly in my api controller